# Creating a simple array with multiple values in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

Arrays have always been my downfall in every language I've worked with, but I'm in a situation where I really need to create a dynamic array of multiple items in Rails (note - none of these are related to a model).

Briefly, each element of the array should hold 3 values - a word, it's language, and a translation into English. For example, here's what I'd like to do:

```
myArray = Array.new
```

And then I'd like to push some values to the array (note - the actual content is taken from elsewhere - although not a model - and will need to be added via a loop, rather than hard coded as it is here):

```
myArray[0] = [["bonjour"], ["French"], ["hello"]]

myArray[1] = [["goddag"], ["Danish"], ["good day"]]

myArray[2] = [["Stuhl"], ["German"], ["chair"]]
```

I would like to create a loop to list each of the items on a single line, something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>bonjour is French for hello</li>
<li>goddag is Danish for good day</li>
<li>Stuhl is German for chair</li>
</ul>
```

However, I'm struggling to (a) work out how to push multiple values to a single array element and (b) how I would loop through and display the results.

Unfortunately, I'm not getting very far at all. I can't seem to work out how to push multiple values to a single array element (what normally happens is that the [] brackets get included in the output, which I obviously don't want - so it's possibly a notation error).

Should I be using a hash instead?

At the moment, I have three separate arrays, which is what I've always done, but I don't particularly like - that is, one array to hold the original word, one array to hold the language, and a final array to hold the translation. While it works, I'm sure this is a better approach - if I could work it out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's say you have the words you'd like in a CSV file:

```
# words.csv
bonjour,French,hello
goddag,Danish,good day
stuhl,German,chair
```

Now in our program we can do the following:

```
words = []
File.open('words.csv').each do |line|
  # chomp removes the newline at the end of the line
  # split(',') will split the line on commas and return an array of the values
  # We then push the array of values onto our words array
  words.push(line.chomp.split(','))
end
```

After this code is executed, the words array had three items in it, each item is an array that is based off of our file.

```
words[0]  # => ["bonjour", "French", "hello"]
words[1]  # => ["goddag", "Danish", "good day"]
words[2]  # => ["stuhl", "German", "chair"]
```

Now we want to display these items.

```
puts "<ul>"
words.each do |word|
  # word is an array, word[0], word[1] and word[2] are available
  puts "<li>#{word[0]} is #{word[1]} for #{word[2]}</li>"
end
puts "</ul>"
```

This gives the following output:

```
<ul>
<li>bonjour is French for hello</li>
<li>goddag is Danish for good day</li>
<li>stuhl is German for chair</li>
</ul>
```

Also, you didn't ask about it, but you can access part of a given array by using the following:

```
words[0][1]  # => "French"
```

This is telling ruby that you want to look at the first (Ruby arrays are zero based) element of the words array.  Ruby finds that element (["bonjour", "French", "hello"]) and sees that it's also an array.  You then asked for the second item ([1]) of that array and Ruby returns the string "French".

Comment: Also, the syntax words = [] and words = Array.new are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me some clues. Unfortunately, however, the content is coming in from different sources - nothing as neat and tidy as a CSV file! But it's a start - cheers!

Comment: The CSV file was just an example. If you have an array of word, language, translation, you can push it into your myArray with myArray.push(...).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
myArray.map{|s|"<li>#{[s[0],'is',s[1],'for',s[2]].join(" ")}</li>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys! I managed to figure a solution out based on your advice

For the benefit of anyone else who stumbles across this problem, here's my elided code. NB: I use three variables called text, language and translation, but I suppose you could replace these with a single array with three separate elements, as Jason suggests above.

In the Controller (content is being added via a loop):

```
#loop start

my_array.push(["#{text}", "#{language}", "#{translation}"]) 

#loop end
```

In the View:

```
<ul>

<% my_array.each do |item| %>

<li><%= item[0] # 0 is the original text %> is 
<%= item[1] # 1 is the language %> for 
<%= item[2] # 2 is the translation %></li>

<% end %>

</ul>
```

Thanks again!